# Webservice, Axis & OSGI (knopflerfish)

Tags: web-services, tomcat, osgi, axis, knopflerfish

I first warn you because I'm a beginner. So, I don't know if I'll be specific on all points. Here is my problem:

I have a wsdl file. Currently, I use Tomcat and Axis to deploy it. So for that, I use the wsdl2java tool of axis that generates me the "skeleton" of the webservice. And then I write on the generated files the code of the various methods of the webservice. Finally, I deploy the webservice on tomcat with Axis. Everything seems to work more or less.

The problem is that I want to deploy this webservice using the bundle axis of osgi (knopflerfish). But I don't know how to do it.

Should we use again the wsdl file and generate a code with a tool like wsdl2java but adapted to knopflerfish? or should I use the "skeleton" that I've created before with Axis and adapte it for osgi? And generally speaking, how can we use the axis  bundle of knopflerfish?

To be honest, I do not find many things over internet about it. So that's why I write to the community :(

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found a article on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-OSGi/ for deploying a Webservice as OSGI bundles. This uses Eclipse Equinox as the OSGi container and Apache CXF as a web services framework and its deployed in Apache Servlet Container.Hope this meets requirement of depolying Webservices as OSGI service .

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it's not exactly what I was looking for. Because in the article, they develop the webservice from the beginning. In my case, I already have a wsdl file but don't know how to use it with osgi. :(